# How to auto-generate Angular model.ts (interface) based on graphql schema?

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, code-generation, graphql-codegen

I want to auto-generate Angular/Typescript model.ts (interface) from graphql schema.

Added `"@graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular": "3.4.12",` in **package.json**

**In codegen.yaml**

````
/src/models/model.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript-apollo-angular```

Couldn't find out what npm script needs to be run to generate Andular/Typescript 
models/interfaces. Tried few things but not working
````